# Can you use lvresize -r to both ext and xfs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel

I was wondering instead of using `lvextend` and then using `xfs_growfs` or `resize2fs`, can I just use `lvresize -r` option to extend the volume and the filesystem together? For xfs, the volume has to be mounted and for ext4, do I have to unmount first? How do I verify the that the underlying filesystem has also be extended ?

Comment: It works for both filesystem types, and you don't have to unmount ext4 filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `lvresize -r` (or `lvextend -r` if you prefer using `lvextend`) with both XFS and Ext4 (ReiserFS is also supported) and you don't need to mount the XFS logical volume, [`fsadm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsadm) (tool which LVM uses for resizing the filesystem) will do a temporary mount to be able to resize XFS.

> How do I verify the that the underlying filesystem has also be extended ?

If you run `lvresize` manually a not from a script you can simply check from the output, it prints information about both the LV and filesystem resize:

```
  Size of logical volume test/lvol0 changed from 248,00 MiB (62 extents) to 260,00 MiB (65 extents).
  Logical volume test/lvol0 successfully resized.
...
meta-data=/dev/mapper/test-lvol0  isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=15872 blks
...
data blocks changed from 63488 to 66560
```

You can see both the LV and the XFS filesystem were resized to 260 MiB (for XFS 66560 blocks with 4096 block size).

And you can always compare the LV and filesystem size using `lvs` and `xfs_info` or `dumpe2fs`.

Comment: ```lvs``` is showing the volume size as 588.00m but ```dump2fs``` is showing things in blocks and inodes. I am not sure how to check if the filesystem (ext4) is also 588MiB

Comment: From `dump2fs` simply multiply `Block count` line with `Block size`.